# AWS Codebuild: Decrypted Variables Error: RequestError: send request failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I keep getting this aws codebuild error in one of my aws regions. i checked my ssm and it seems fine. any help why this is happening?
[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344)